# Python scalable parallel processing for small calculations

Tags: python, data-science, dask, dask-distributed

I'm working on a project that is essentially numerical integration (Runge-Kutta) for the path of potentially hundreds of particles in a vector field. I have explored using Dask to parallelize the task but I'm not sure if my problem aligns with Dask's specialty. Dask is good for operating on larger than memory data by leveraging parallel processing (where each calculation could take a minute). My problem is more about 100,000s of 1 second calculations.

Just to show what one of the calculations would be:

```
def RK4(field, x0, y0, t0, dt):
    k1x, k1y = field.interpolate(x0, y0, t0) #predefined interpolation routine using scipy.interpolate
    xi = x0+.5*k1x*dt
    yi = y0+.5*k1x*dt
    k2x, k2y = field.interpolate(xi, yi, t0+.5*dt)
    xi = x0+.5*k2x*dt
    yi = y0+.5*k2x*dt
    k3x, k3y = field.interpolate(xi, yi, t0+.5*dt)
    xi = x0+k3x*dt
    yi = y0+k3x*dt
    k4x, k4y = field.interpolate(xi, yi, t0+dt)

    xi = x0+1/6*(k1x*dt+2*k2x*dt+2*k3x*dt+k4x*dt)
    yi = y0+1/6*(k1y*dt+2*k2y*dt+2*k3y*dt+k4y*dt)

    return xi, yi, t0+dt
```

The above would run on each of 100s of particles about 100 times. The ability to scale on HPC/cloud is essential. The ideal situation would be doing batches of particles at once but because of the scipy.interpolate dependency, I have a GIL problem.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: RK4 is nice for advanced pedagogical purposes, but for industrial scale number crunching I would propose to use one of the embedded methods like dopri853, Verner87 or a more modern method. Due to the usually larger step sizes and the cheap interpolation in-between, these are as much faster than RK4 as RK4 is faster than Euler for the same accuracy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dask is typically used for on-disk or distributed data processing, it's not the best tool to use in this particular case.

Instead, consider using Cython/Numba/Pypy to implement number-crunching, like in the example of yours. This will bypass GIL by pre-compiling functions into binary libraries, which CPython can then use natively. This results in 5-10x speedup, depending on a task at hand.

Moreover, if your particles can be processed in parallel, you should consider multiprocessing/ray to further leverage multiple cpu cores.

If you do this two steps and still struggle with performance, check algorithm asymptotics and look for the alternative algorithm.